# R's equivalence of numpy.linalg.lstsq

Tags: r, numpy

I have multiple linear regressions of the form vc = x1 * va + x2 * vb.

(Now, a too minimal example follows - it has the same values, which leads to warnings in R. Below a second data set illustrating my issue)

In Python, I programmed

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np

va = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
vb = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
vc = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

A = np.vstack([va, vb]).T

print(A)

result = np.linalg.lstsq(A, vc)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
(array([ 0.5,  0.5]), array([], dtype=float64), 1, array([  1.04880885e+01,   3.14018492e-16]))
```

I thought, following code would be identical:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

va <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
vb <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
vc <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

reg <- lm(vc ~ va + vb)

reg

summary(reg)
```

However, I get following output (excerpt):

```
Coefficients:
A1  A2  
 1  NA  

esidual standard error: 7.022e-16 on 4 degrees of freedom

In summary.lm(reg) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

Even if I adjust the numbers somehow, R still keeps complaining.

I assume, I am doing something basic wrong, but I can't figure out. I also tried to construct a matrix `A` (containg `vb` and `vc` as colums) and then use `reg <- lm(vc ~ 0 + A)`. There, I get 3 degrees of freedom, but with the same Coefficients.

### 2nd data set

```
va = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
vb = np.array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
vc = np.array([3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5])

va <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
vb <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
vc <- c(3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5)
```

If I add `0 +` (which results in `lm(vc ~ 0 + va + vb)`), I geed 3 degrees of freedom and the same result. Looks good.

The `0 +` removes the "implied intercept term" (whatever this this). [Source](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html)

Comment: you seem to believe the output of python rather than r

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong....your data has a perfect linear relationship. It says so in the warning. Try adding some variation and it will work fine.

Comment: Try this and see for yourself. Even a very small variation in the data produces proper coefficients and standard error calculations. `va <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) + rnorm(5, 0, 0.01); vb <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) + rnorm(5, 0, 0.01); vc <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) + rnorm(5, 0, 0.01)`

Comment: I think, my issue is to understand the effect of the precence/absence of `0 + ` in the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a singular fit, and multiple combinations of coefficients will represent it equally well. IMHO, both `numpy` and `R` should really throw an error in this case by default. You can get `R` to give you an error by adding `singular.ok = FALSE` to your arguments. Additionally, altough your intercept in this case is zero, your regression equation indicates that you're not looking to fit one. To fit a linear model without an intercept in `R`, use a formula in the form:

```
lm(vc ~ va + vb - 1)
```

So, to (properly) return an error in this singular fit, you would call:

```
reg <- lm(vc ~ va + vb - 1,  singular.ok = FALSE)
```

Comment: Why the `-1` in the formula?

Comment: It removes the Intercept. `0 +` in your second example does the same thing.